# Could not show pdf file name correctly in Primefaces

Tags: pdf, jsf, primefaces

I am developing jsf page and using primefaces. While doing this pdf name is displaying "dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml". And I would like to show pdf with pdf name. How can I do?

```
<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dialogView" modal="false">
                <h:form id="form">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                        <p:media value="#{bean.streamedContent}"
                            player="pdf" width="1000px" height="750px">
                            <f:param name="bean.selectedFile.fileName"
                                value="#{bean.generateRandomIdForNotCaching()}" />
                        </p:media>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

And here is my code;

```
public void showFile() {
        setStreamedContent(new DefaultStreamedContent(getData(selectedFile.getFileName()), "application/pdf",
                "downloaded_" + selectedFile.getFileName()));
    }

    private InputStream getData(String fileName) {
        File folder = new File(folderFile);
        File file = new File(folder + "\\" + fileName);

        InputStream fileView = null;
        try {
            fileView = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileView;
    }

    public String generateRandomIdForNotCaching() {
        return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```

Comment: @Kukeltje I couldnt solve and find any solution on 'search engine' . There is a thing called 'brain' and sometimes some people don't use it. Try to use it? Also I tried second answer's solution but not working.

Comment: If I were you, I would not delete my rude comments in above. I know dont worry but you can spend more time with them.

Comment: My comment was NOT rude, you interpreted it as such since you did not read about [ask]. I can spend only  a certain amount of time on questions and the bad ones (showing little effort) do not always get the attention they want. Good luck. (remarkable that another comment of mine is removed and not by me)

Comment: Your comment was rude so it is removed by editor. Good luck you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try PrimeFaces Extensions Document Viewer it gives you much more control over how to load PDF and gives you control over the download file name for streamed content.

> download =If streamed content this will be the name of the download
>   file. NOTE: Must end in .pdf for PDF.js to pick it up!

Link: [PrimeFaces Extensions Document Viewer](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf)

Comment: Thank u very much sir.